# Bypass SSL Cert check in VB.net webbrowser

Tags: vb.net, internet-explorer, https

I hope you can help me. I searched the whole internet, found loads of different tips and steps of how to do it and nothing works for me.

I build a simple application which has Webbrowser1 embedded. Soon I found that many websites does not display correctly so I found that a regsitry key can be tweeked to make the application to use IE11.

Now I have the issue with HTTPS:// self signed certifcation.

Basically in my Apllication the website displays:
[image]

In IE11 browser I get the 
[image]

Basically if the "go on to the webpage (not recommended)" was in my app I would not have a problem. But instead I have the "Error Code:0".

- I tried bypassing this in IE11 internet options > advanced > security
- I tried adding the website I am interested to open inside Trusted Sites
- I tried to follow steps on the interent for IE11 to simply bypass this security feature
- I tried looking for the way to bypass this on VB using

  ```
  ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
          New RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(Function() True)
  ```

The above line maybe works, but I don't know how to utilize it.

To summarize;
I have webbrowser1, textbox1, button1. When I click on button1 it does webbrowser1.navigate(textbox1.text). It works on every website like a harm except the https with expired certs etc.

What do I need to do to have the possibility to display those https websites?

Comment: The line you provided just needs to be placed anywhere in your form, try it in constuctor

Comment: I added  `Public Sub New()
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = New RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(Function() True)
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub` after Public Class Form1 and I still get the same ERROR CODE:0

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you must always call `InitializeComponent()` _**before**_ you do anything else.